# How do I prevent users from accessing a page by typing the URL?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

How do I prevent users from accessing a page by typing the URL. I'm using stripe and the url it redirects to is /paymentsuccess. How do I prevent all user from accessing this page?

I have another route that redirects after the success page, so I can't even add a middleware to skip the page.

Comment: Why don't you rename your route to `/paymentsuccess`?

Comment: Sorry if my question is asked in a confusing way, so the thing is when the payment is done on stripe it redirects to the page /paymentsuccess. but if someone types that directly in the url they can get the item without paying. so how do I prevent this?

Comment: But isn't there an unguessable code somewhere in the URL, like in `/paymentsuccess?code=ad56a...`, and you must verify that code before delivering the item? Can you describe the whole payment flow in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

The loading of the `/paymentsuccess` page is *not* the trigger for you to deliver the item. Instead, Stripe makes a separate webhook call to your server after payment has completed as described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#create-event-handler).